# How do I fetch the price data from CoinGecko?

Tags: bitcoin-core, api, documentation

I don't understand their API: https://www.coingecko.com/en/api

It says:

> /simple/price    Get the current price of any cryptocurrencies in any
>   other supported currencies that you need.

But then you click it and it doesn't spit out any JSON at all. Instead, it shows a number of id fields and other things. I can't make it open the actual URL for displaying the Bitcoin price.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that will give you the simple price:

`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd`

The page lets you try out the API by filling in the form fields. You can get the list of coin ids from:

`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list`

and the compare currencies from:

`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/supported_vs_currencies`

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged because they tend to be broken quickly.

Comment: I changed the answer to remove links.